# Load only Configurable product of order not child simple product

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

I want to get all the ordered items by **order id**. But if **configurable product** then I want to get only **parent item** id not it's **child product**.

For this I am using following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();`
```

So, How can I skip child products of configurable products?

Comment: Please do not use the object manager

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($orderItems as $order){ 
    if($order->getProductType() == 'simple'){
        continue;
    }
}
```

You can skip using above condition.

Comment: Please do not not use the objectmanager